# comparing two Binary images in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, euclidean-distance, binary-image

I have two binary images of hand which are almost same.How should I compare them to know whether they represent almost same shape or not.I have tried finding euclidean distance between two images but its not giving correct answer if the image is slightly changed or moved to left or right or slight decrease in size.I have also tried HOG descriptors in opencv still I am unable to get correct answer if I compare more than one image.What is the best way to compare two binary images based on shape or any feature to know nearly matching images not considering the size of the image.Links to images are http://postimg.org/image/w20tuuzmv/ and http://postimg.org/image/jndr4br9x/

Answer (score 0):

I think that Generalized Hough transform might be a good solution for you. [Here](http://www.business-to-technology.com/generalized-hough-transform/) is a tutorial about it.

Alternatively uou can try to cut hand from one image (just use contour bounding rect) and than use it as a template and search for it in second image using template matching technique - [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) you can read more about. When you will find point with highest correlation value, you need to decide whether it is big enough - you need to find threshold on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Are the images just rotated, translated and scaled? If so you could compute the principal components of the images using PCA, then rotate the images so that the first component is in a certain direction (e.g. always vertical) you could then compute the centroids of the images and translate them to be always in the same position (e.g. center of the image), to use always the same scale you could resize the images so that the sum of the distances between each white pixel with the centroid is the same in both images. Now it's easy to compare the images for example `score = np.sum(A==B)`